# Access VBA Check Date time, if greater than today 3:00 PM, then vb question error message

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a request form that has a submit button.  On click, I would like for access to check the submit date to see if it is greater than 3:00 pm today.  If yes, then a message box appears for you to change the requested date and resubmit.

This is what I tried, but errors out.

Please assist if possible

```
Dim mDate As Date
mDate = DateValue(Me.tblEntered)
IIf (mDate > "3:00 pm")
    If MsgBox("You are submitting a request after the 3:00 PM cutoff time. " & Chr(13) & _
    "You should change your request to the next day.  Do you want to change your request date?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2) = vbNo Then
    DoCmd.Save
Else
    MsgBox "Please make changes and resubmit"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use *DateDiff* for this:

```vb
Dim mDate As Date

' If tblEntered is text:
mDate = CDate(Me!tblEntered.Value)
' If tblEntered is DateTime:
mDate = Me!tblEntered.Value

If DateDiff("n", DateAdd("h", 15, Date), mDate) > 0 Then
    If MsgBox("You are submitting a request after the 3:00 PM cutoff time. " & vbCrLf & _
        "You should change your request to the next day.  Do you want to change your request date?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2) = vbNo Then
    DoCmd.Save
Else
    MsgBox "Please make changes and resubmit."
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors with your code (missing "End If", Using "IIf" instead of "If", Flow of your date check yes/no response)

I don't know the format/content of your source: Me.tblEntered  is it just a date or is it Date & Time? If includes time, then alter my "Date + #3:00:00 PM#"

```
Dim mDate As Date
mDate = DateValue(Me.tblEntered)

If (mDate > Date + #3:00:00 PM#) Then       ' Today at 3PM
    If MsgBox("You are submitting a request after the 3:00 PM cutoff time. " & Chr(13) & _
        "You should change your request to the next day.  Do you want to change your request date?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2) = vbNo Then
        DoCmd.Save
    Else
        MsgBox "Please make changes and resubmit"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: yes, the source is date and time, when you say alter what should I alter?   When I add the code and run, it closes the form.

Comment: For clarification, I assume you don't care what time the Submit button is clicked, you only care about the date/time value that is in 'Me.tblEntered'? As for the form being closed, we have no idea what code you did not include. Your logic checks if it is after 3PM, and if so, asks if you want to save. If it is BEFORE 3PM, what do you want to do? Save it also? If so, add an "Else" and "DoCmd.Save"

Answer (score 0):

In a query use:

```
IIf(Format([DateCreated],"hh")>=15,"after 3","before 3")
```

In VBA use:

```
Dim mDate As Date

If format(mDate,"hh") >= 15 Then       ' Today at 3PM
    If MsgBox("You are submitting a request after the 3:00 PM cutoff time. " & Chr(13) & _
        "You should change your request to the next day.  Do you want to change your request date?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2) = vbNo Then
        DoCmd.Save
    Else
        MsgBox "Please make changes and resubmit"
    End If
End If
```